# Feeding Apache Spark Streaming from Amazon SQS?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-sqs

Spark can be fed in many ways as it is explained in the documentation (like Kafka, Flume, Twitter, ZeroMQ, Kinesis or plain old TCP sockets).
Does anybody know how to feed Spark Streaming from Amazon SQS?

Comment: Asking in the user mailing list of Spark might help.

Comment: Thanks, I supposed nobody else is responding here ...

Comment: @antoneti what lib did you end up using? any recommendations?

Answer (score 8):

There's a github project called spark-sql-receiver. It's been uploaded to the maven repository with the groupId of com.github.imapi artifactId of spark-sqs-receiver_2.10. It's currently on version 1.0.1. By the looks of the [github project](https://github.com/imapi/spark-sqs-receiver), it's being actively maintained as well. The following is some sample code shamelessly copied from the project's README.md file:

```
ssc.receiverStream(new SQSReceiver("sample")
      .credentials(<key>, <secret>)
      .at(Regions.US_EAST_1)
      .withTimeout(2))
```

Comment: how can we achieve similar operation with pyspark? Is it even possible? Thank you.